# How to direct errors from with a find exec command to a log file

Tags: bash, logging, find, exec

Hi I have the following command that does yui optimizations and runs as a cron job. I want to log the output of the command to a log file.

```
find . -type d -exec bash -c "cd '{}' && pwd && java -jar /opt/yui/yui.jar -o '.css$:.css' *.css" \; > log
```

This command logs the output of find but not the output of yui.jar. that is logged to the console. Any way to log that to the same file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This command logs the output of find but not the output of yui.jar.

You will need to redirect the output then, something like

```
 ...java -jar /opt/yui/yui.jar -o '.css$:.css' *.css >logfile 2>errorlog ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to log both the "yui.jar" output and the "find" one, you have to add the redirect in quotation marks, like this:

```
find . -type d -exec bash -c "cd '{}' && pwd && java -jar /opt/yui/yui.jar -o '.css$:.css' *.css >> log" \; >> log
```

and maybe you want to specify a different name for the log file other than "log"...

Comment: Won't redirecting both to the same file cause data loss?

Comment: The command indeed causes data loss. The log file that gets created only has the output from the main command, not the result from yui.jar